# Multiple choice quiz that retrieves data from a database - problems looping through questions

Tags: vb.net

I am having problems with my multiple choice quiz. When I click next and back it doesn't show the different questions from the database, the radiobuttons and labels don't change to show the different questions or the answers. Sorry if this is confusing.

Code is below

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
  " Data Source= C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Normalised Database.accdb"

Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
Dim provider As String
Dim dataFile As String
Dim no As Integer
'    Dim q(no) As String
Dim quesnum As Integer = 1
Dim answer As String
Dim selected As String
Dim score As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    no = CInt(InputBox("Input the number of questions you want. You can choose from 1 to 10."))
    QuesNo.Hide()
    QuesLabel.Hide()
    Label3.Hide()
    RadioButton1.Hide()
    RadioButton2.Hide()
    RadioButton3.Hide()
    RadioButton4.Hide()
    NextBtn.Hide()
    BackBtn.Hide()
    BackBtn.Hide()
    SaveBtn.Hide()
    ReturnBtn.Hide()

    For i = 1 To no
        question()
        mark()

    Next

    'End
End Sub

Private Sub question()

    cn.ConnectionString = ConnectString
    cn.Open()

    ' quesnum = 0
    '   quesnum = quesnum + 1
    QuesNo.Text = "Question " & quesnum & " of " & no

    cm.CommandText = "SELECT Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, CorrectAnswer FROM Question"
    cm.Connection = cn

    dr = cm.ExecuteReader

    Dim answerList As New List(Of String)

    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Read()
        QuesLabel.Text = CStr(dr.Item("Question"))

        answerList.Add(CStr(dr.Item("Answer1")))
        answerList.Add(CStr(dr.Item("Answer2")))
        answerList.Add(CStr(dr.Item("Answer3")))
        answerList.Add(CStr(dr.Item("CorrectAnswer")))
        answerList = RandomizeListOrder(answerList)
        RadioButton1.Text = answerList(0)
        RadioButton2.Text = answerlist(1)
        RadioButton3.Text = answerList(2)
        RadioButton4.Text = answerlist(3)
        dr.Close()
    End If
    cn.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub mark()
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then selected = RadioButton1.Text
    If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then selected = RadioButton2.Text
    If RadioButton3.Checked = True Then selected = RadioButton3.Text
    If RadioButton4.Checked = True Then selected = RadioButton4.Text


    cn.ConnectionString = ConnectString
    cn.Open()
    cm.CommandText = "SELECT CorrectAnswer FROM Question"
    cm.Connection = cn
    dr = cm.ExecuteReader
    If dr.HasRows Then
        dr.Read()
        answer = CStr(dr.Item("CorrectAnswer"))
        dr.Close()

    End If
    cn.Close()

    If selected = answer Then
        score = score + 1
    End If

    '   question()

    Label3.Text = "score is " & score

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NextBtn.Click

    For i = 1 To no
        question()

        mark()

    Next
    quesnum = quesnum + 1
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles StartBtn.Click

    QuesNo.Show()
    QuesLabel.Show()
    Label3.Show()
    RadioButton1.Show()
    RadioButton2.Show()
    RadioButton3.Show()
    RadioButton4.Show()
    NextBtn.Show()
    BackBtn.Show()
    SaveBtn.Show()
    ReturnBtn.Show()
    StartBtn.Hide()

End Sub

Private Function RandomizeListOrder(ByVal answers As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)

    Dim answer2 As Integer
    Dim rnd As New Random
    'loop though each item in the list
    For answer1 As Integer = 0 To answers.Count - 1
        'pick a random answer
        answer2 = rnd.Next(0, answers.Count - 1)
        'If answer1 and answer2 are the same then skip the rest of the code
        'in the loop and go onto the next question
        If answer1 = answer2 Then
            Continue For
        End If
        'swap the questions over
        Dim temp As String
        temp = answers(answer1)
        answers(answer1) = answers(answer2)
        answers(answer2) = temp
    Next
    'return the list of answers
    Return answers

End Function

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BackBtn.Click

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: The next and back buttons allow you to go forwards and back through the questions? Also what is the purpose of the two loops around the question sub? If they are for looping through the questions then the code the goes through the questions will need re-writing really. Let me know you want them to work and I'll have a go

Comment: `When I click next and back it doesn't show the different questions from the database` <-- this is not a problem, it's a task. You need to spent some time yourself, investigate and provide specific technical details for us to help you.

Comment: Also, your SELECT query may need modifying - would you be able to email me the question database to the address in my profile please?

Comment: I will send you the database through email, I am trying to solve it but I'm finding it really hard. Yes the next and back buttons are for going forwards and back through questions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem - Thanks for the DB.  I'm having a look now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK In your original code, there was no question number being passed to the `question()` procedure. So, I changed the declaration to ..

```
Private Sub question(quesnum As Integer)
```

Then I removed the question loop out of the Form_Load procedure as it shouldn't have been there and should have been written into the `mark` procedure like this

```
If quesnum < no Then
        quesnum += 1
End If
```

I've changed your query command in your `question` procedure to

```
cm.CommandText = "SELECT CorrectAnswer FROM Question WHERE QuestionNo = " & quesnum.ToString
```

so that now it gets a particular question depending on the `quesnum` variable.

I've also done the same sort of thing in the `mark` procedure when the query gets the correct answer from the database.

Finally I added `If` statements into your `Back` and `Next` button clicks to make sure that the user couldnt go beyond the start or end of the questions.

OK That's pretty much it, but there are certainly still a couple of problems

- How are you going detect when all the questions have been answered
- How are you tracking which questions are answered? - At the moment, a user can
  answer question 1, go to question 2, then go back to the question 1 and answer it again and get another point added to their score.
- Finally you need to add a check to make sure that the user doesn't enter a number that is greater than the number of questions in the database.

Have fun - Hope all this helps. Below is the complete code

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim ConnectString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & " Data Source= C:\Users\Sales\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Normalised Database.accdb"
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
    Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim no As Integer
    Dim q(no) As String
    Dim quesnum As Integer
    Dim answer As String
    Dim selected As String
    Dim score As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        no = CInt(InputBox("Input the number of questions you want. You can choose from 1 to 10."))
        Label1.Hide()
        Label2.Hide()
        Label3.Hide()
        RadioButton1.Hide()
        RadioButton2.Hide()
        RadioButton3.Hide()
        RadioButton4.Hide()
        Button1.Hide()
        Button2.Hide()
        Button2.Hide()
        Button3.Hide()
        Button4.Hide()
    End Sub

    Private Sub question(quesnum As Integer)
        cn.ConnectionString = ConnectString
        cn.Open()
        Label1.Text = "Question " & quesnum & " of " & no
        'your query now selects a specific question number with the addition of WHERE QuestionNo = " & quesnum.ToSring
        cm.CommandText = "SELECT Question, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, CorrectAnswer FROM Question WHERE QuestionNo = " & quesnum.ToString
        cm.Connection = cn
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        Dim answerList As New List(Of String)
        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            Label2.Text = dr.Item("Question").ToString
            answerList.Add(dr.Item("Answer1").ToString)
            answerList.Add(dr.Item("Answer2").ToString)
            answerList.Add(dr.Item("Answer3").ToString)
            answerList.Add(dr.Item("CorrectAnswer").ToString)
            answerList = RandomizeListOrder(answerList)
            RadioButton1.Text = answerList(0)
            RadioButton2.Text = answerList(1)
            RadioButton3.Text = answerList(2)
            RadioButton4.Text = answerList(3)
            dr.Close()
        End If
        cn.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub mark()
        'See the function below
        selected = CheckedRadioButtonText()
        cn.ConnectionString = ConnectString
        cn.Open()
        'same again here for selecting the correct answer from the correct question
        cm.CommandText = "SELECT CorrectAnswer FROM Question WHERE QuestionNo = " & quesnum.ToString
        cm.Connection = cn
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            dr.Read()
            answer = dr.Item("CorrectAnswer").ToString
            dr.Close()
        End If
        cn.Close()
        'Here is where the point where quesnum is incremented to get ready to load
        'The next question after the current one has been marked
        If selected = answer Then score = score + 1
        MsgBox("score is " & score)
    End Sub

    'This function checks all the radio buttons to see which one is checked
    ' and returns the text of that RadioButton
    Private Function CheckedRadioButtonText() As String
        If RadioButton1.Checked Then
            Return RadioButton1.Text
        ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked Then
            Return RadioButton2.Text
        ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked Then
            Return RadioButton3.Text
        Else
            Return RadioButton4.Text
        End If
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        mark()
        'move to next question 
        If quesnum < no Then
            quesnum += 1
        End If
        question(quesnum)
    End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Move to previous question
    If quesnum > 1 Then
        quesnum -= 1
    End If
    question(quesnum)
End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Label1.Show()
        Label2.Show()
        Label3.Show()
        RadioButton1.Show()
        RadioButton2.Show()
        RadioButton3.Show()
        RadioButton4.Show()
        Button1.Show()
        Button2.Show()
        Button3.Show()
        Button4.Show()
        Button5.Hide()
        'Set the first question from here. 
        quesnum = 1
        question(quesnum)
    End Sub

    Private Function RandomizeListOrder(answers As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
        Dim answer2 As Integer
        Dim rnd As New Random
        'loop though each item in the list
        For answer1 As Integer = 0 To answers.Count - 1
            'pick a random answer
            answer2 = rnd.Next(0, answers.Count - 1)
            'If answer1 and answer2 are the same then skip the rest of the code
            'in the loop and go onto the next question
            If answer1 = answer2 Then
                Continue For
            End If
            'swap the questions over
            Dim temp As String
            temp = answers(answer1)
            answers(answer1) = answers(answer2)
            answers(answer2) = temp
        Next
        'return the list of answers
        Return answers
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: ran it on my machine and it works perfectly, thank you! going to work through the problems now as well

Comment: Brilliant! Glad to help.  With the answer tracking. You might just be best creating a boolean array and using Redim to resize it when you know how many questions there will be. When a question is marked as correct,  set the same array element using quesnum to true and get the score from how many elements in the array are true.

Comment: I think i'll have a go creating the array, I might probably create another question or ask for help here but I'm going to give it a go. And as for the problem where the input is bigger than the database, I just used a loop where the program won't continue unless the input is less than 10 which is less than the database. Also do you think it would be possible to shuffle the questions so that each test the order would be different?

Comment: The problem with the loops is that using the Back button to go back to previous questions as well will cause problems. You're better just sticking with quesnum as the index and checking it each time the user clicks next - or on the last question, change the text of the button to "Finish" and adding code in the button to do whatever you want to do after the questions have been answered.

Comment: as far as randomizing the questions is concerned, You could create a `Structure` object to hold the question data and then load all your questions from the database into a list of this structure. Then you can randomize the list in the same way that the new `RandomizeListOrder` function does. In fact - that function could be modified a little and you could use that instead of having two separate randomizeList functions

Comment: what kind of code would I use to hold the question data would it be sort of like a "new dataset" type thing?